# mvc generate captcha after failed login attempt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, partial-views, recaptcha

so i was able to make my recaptcha thing working but my problem is though, i want to have it appear only after 3 tries. one option that i have is to redirect the user to a View that will have the captcha already (duplicate of the login but with captcha) and then have him log in through that page. is there any other option? i feel like partial views would cause problems on Post of the page. what do you think is the best way to generate the captcha?

```
    <% using(Html.BeginForm()) {%>
      <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
      <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username) %>
      <br /><br />
      <label>Password:</label>
      <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      <%: Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "") %>
      <%: Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "Password", "") %>
      <%: Html.ActionLink("Forgot Username", "Username", "") %>


      <%: ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "thisismykey", theme: "red") %>


    <% } %>
```

THanks,
G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in a model (hopefully a ViewModel). Why not add `NumberOfFailedLogins` to it?

Then you could just put a bit of code around the `Recaptcha` saying

```
<%: if (Model.NumberofFailedLogins > 3) { %>
<%: ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "thisismykey", theme: "red") %>
<% } %>
```

NOTE: I am used to Razor syntax, so apologies if the above is not perfect. I'm sure you get the idea!

Obviously you would need to update `NumberOfFailedLogins` behind the scenes!

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, the number of failed login attempts ought to be recorded in the membership database behind the scenes automatically (the act of attempting to login would do this; note that the [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx) automatically records the number of consecutive failed login attempts out of the box) and it is from there that the ViewModel obtains this information. So it doesn't matter if you are using a bot to attempt to brute-force your way in, it can still be presented with the ReCaptcha after three attempts (and of course can be locked out too if desired).

Comment: interesting, well, im storing the fialed attempts in a cookie. let me try that out real quick.

Comment: Please remember that it's not a good idea to keep it in your cookies, unless they are encrypted... In any other way machine that is trying to hack/force your system can fake cookie info and send it to you...

Comment: so do you suggest just using the whole model thing? i was able to make it work btw, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Sadly, this wont work for one main reason: If I'm a hacker trying to bruteforce your login, my bot doesnt re-post to the page that was returned to it when it failed, it only posts directly to the initial login page, so any client side variables containing number of failed attempts will be bypassed (especially in cookies). Ergo, you'd need to use the session perhaps?

Comment: @Jimbo: My intention was that the number of failed logins for a user is recorded behind the scenes (in the membership database) and the `NumberOfFailedLogins` property of the model is read from the database. That way, it doesn't matter how you access the URL.  The point being that you don't need to pass the model back to the controller; it doesn't rely on client-side variables (indeed the `NumberOfFailedLogins` is not available client-side in my code example). I hope this makes sense!

Comment: I would like to know your approach for zeroing the "NumberOfFailedLogins". If user leaves the page after first failed attempt and comes back after a day or some hours